# SSH to localhost on android

Tags: ssh, termux

I am trying to get ssh working on my android phone. I am currently able to ssh out, from my phone to another device. But I am struggling to be able to ssh in. To test things, I am just working on my the phone and trying to establish an ssh connection with localhost.

Working in termux, I ran the command

`ssh localhost -p 8022`

Then I am given the prompt

`u0_a316@localhost's password:`

I'm struggling a bit to understand this. I know that u0_a316 should be a user on my phone, but I don't quite know how users on the android oprating system work. I tried entering the lock screen password I have for myself, as well as no password. But neither of these work. Could someone help explain whats going on here, or point me to some (hopefully not too dense) documentation on this?

*this question is cross posted from stackoverflow, following a recommendation in the comments*

Comment: Android uses user accounts to separate each app in it's own sandbox. Therefore every installed app gets it's own user account.

Comment: gotcha, so I should be able to set a password just for this app? @Robert

Comment: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access#SSH

Comment: No you can't change the password, all user accounts are managed by Android and they are not designed to be used for user authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to set a password for your Termux session. You will not be asked for it at any time when you start Termux, so it is safe to do. Just type:

```
passwd <enter>
```

and type in a password. You will be asked to repeat it to confirm.

So when you ssh to your phone from another device/machine, this will be the password required. The command to type on the other machine will be:

```
ssh u0_a316@<your_phone's_IP> -p 8022
```